# How can we change language in JTextField?

Tags: java

How can I change the language in a `JTextField` while running? For example I want to type Chinese so I must change keyboard (Shift+alt).

Answer (score 3):

You can change the locale used in `JTextField` with [`InputContext.selectInputMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/im/InputContext.html#selectInputMethod-java.util.Locale-):

```
JTextField txt = new JTextField();
txt.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(Locale.CHINESE);
```

Comment: but if for Cambodia language we write " txt.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(Locale.CAMBODIA); ".  Is this right?

Comment: @narason `Locale.CAMBODIA` does not exist but you can use the constructor `new Locale("km", "KH")`.

Comment: yes now it work .But why i can not see language it kind small rectangle.How can i convert to cambodia language